# Hosting html with Auth on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, mkdocs

I am using Mkdocs for Generating Documentation and would like to host with firebase but **with Authentication**.

I have [hosted](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/quickstart.html) html without Authentication on firebase and didn't find any solution for authentication.

Any help is appreciated.